# Get page source of an iframe after loading its contents

Tags: php, iframe, web-scraping, video-streaming, simple-html-dom

I am **scraping** a video URL from an iframe. I am using file_get_contents('iframe_url'). But I am getting only contents before page load.
For example,

```
<textarea><?php echo file_get_html('https://www.xvideos.com/embedframe/26922703'); ?></textarea>
```

I am getting only

```
<img src='http://static-ss.xvideos-cdn.com/v3/img/skins/default/xvideos.com.png' /><div style='background-color: #FFF'><h1>Please find this video on <a href='https://xvideos.com' target='_blank'>xvideos.com</a> or <a href='https://xvideos.net' target='_blank'>xvideos.net</a></h1></div>
```

But when I right-click on the iframe and click view frame source, then I get the full page source.
So, how to get the iframe page source using PHP after loading its javascript document.

Any help is appreciated.